# Wifi drops off after a little while with Ubuntu 20.04 server on Raspi

Tags: networking, wireless

This has been asked in various forms, and I've tried many approaches to no full avail. Here's my scenario. Raspi 3+ running Ubuntu 20.04 server.

I am folling these instructions: https://forum.dexterindustries.com/t/setup-python3-gopigo3-and-di-sensors-on-ubuntu-server-20-04-64-bit-for-non-root-access/8305:

```
// DOWNLOAD UBUNTU 20.04 Server LTS 64-bit image
https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi


//Flash SD card with Raspberry Pi Imager
  Select the Ubuntu->Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS 64-bit
  or Custom->ubuntu-20.04.2-preinstalled-server-arm64_raspi.img.xz
  (Scroll) Select the 16GB SD Card
```

Which I believe has been used by others...THen:

Wired network works fine. Wireless network works fine but after a certain amount of time (minutes not hours) it just stops working. Here are a variety of data:

I enable wifi with this command (among others that I tried)

```
sudo nmcli d wifi connect myssid password thepassword
```

It works fine without a cable as well. But after a little while it stops working and when I try it again it says:

```
Error: No network with SSID 'myssid' found.
```

I know the network is still there, didn't go anywhere. If I reboot it works fine again.

nmcli by itself shows:

```
wlan0: disconnected
        "Broadcom BCM43438 combo and Bluetooth Low Energy"
        wifi (brcmfmac), B8:27:EB:F0:28:E7, hw, mtu 1500

eth0: unmanaged
        "Microchip 7800"
        ethernet (lan78xx), B8:27:EB:A5:7D:B2, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

tailscale0: unmanaged
        "tailscale0"
        tun, sw, mtu 1280

p2p-dev-wlan0: unmanaged
        "p2p-dev-wlan0"
        wifi-p2p, hw
```

I don't knowwhere p2p-dev-wlan0 came from. I might have done it during trouble shooting. Not sure if it matters.

`route` gives

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.4.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
_gateway        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

### Question:

You see that I am building on a standard ubuntu Raspi image. Given the behavior I am seeing and the listing above, is there anything suspicious that you spot that could explain the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am using. My comment became a mess because of formatting so I moved it to the main body of the question.

Comment: I've never had to run any nmcli commands to get wifi working on a raspi. I've only ever used a wpa_supplicant.conf file for headless setup or the raspi-config command.  You can search these options for more information on each. If the problem is the same after a fresh flash using one or both of those options, I would assume that the problem is with your network or the raspi needs to be relocated to avoid physical or electromagnetic interference

Comment: Thanks! Do you recognize: "p2p-dev-wlan0: unmanaged" and is it normal?

Comment: raspi-config doesn't seem to be included in 20.04 so I would try wpa_supplicant: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/57023